# How to join and get value for first occurrence in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have an employee table that need to join to staff time table to get staff time value on employee_id, date and interval in MS SQL.

If you look at the example below, you will notice that the id 2 and 3 have the same interval. In this case, I want the first value in the records which have the same employee_id, date and interval to have the actual staff time, and zero for the rest, even though all these records will have different ID.

Would you please show me how to achieve this? Thank you for your help everyone!

Employee Table

[image: Employee table]

Staff Time

[image: Staff Time]

This is what I need:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
select a.*, b.staff_time
from employee a
left join staff_time b on 
a.employee_id = b.Employee_ID 
and a.date = b.date 
and a.interval = b.interval
```

And above query produces this:

[image]

Comment: Might you be so kind as to edit your question to include: (1) your expected output and (b) your existing query? That will make it easier for us to help you correct the query. It would also be helpful to know which database software you are using, e.g. by adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: Hi, can you please add an example of the result-set you are trying to produce.

Comment: hi all, I have added what you are requesting in my post. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you add a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with `employee` and match `employee`, `date` and `interval`, but _not_ `id` then you'll know which rows should have zero `staff_time`, easily accommodated with a `CASE` expression. Tip: Use aliases with meaning, e.g. `employee as e`, rather than just starting at the beginning of the alphabet. `employee as emp left outer join employee as emp_match on emp_match.id <> emp.id and ...`.

Comment: Hi Habo, yes I know what rows should have zero but how do I do that with a case statement? Thank you.

Comment: Something like `case when ( emp_match.id is NULL ) or ( emp_match.id > emp.id ) then emp.staff_time else 0 end as staff_time`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to come up with query which gives me what I want but is there anyway to simplify it?

```
select a.id,a.employee_id,a.date,a.interval,a.Staff_Time,
    case when a.rankk = 1 then a.Staff_Time else 0 end new_Staff_Time
    from
    (select a.*, b.staff_time,
    ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by  a.employee_id,a.date,a.interval order by a.date DESC) as rankk
    from employee a
    left join staff_time b on
    a.employee_id = b.Employee_ID 
    and a.date = b.date 
    and a.interval = b.interval) a
    left join
    (
    select a.*, b.staff_time
    from employee a
    left join staff_time b on
    a.employee_id = b.Employee_ID 
    and a.date = b.date 
    and a.interval = b.interval
    ) b on a.id <> b.id and
    a.employee_id = b.Employee_ID 
    and a.date = b.date 
    and a.interval = b.interval
```

Comment: You _really_ need to buy some additional aliases. Reusing `a` and `b` repeatedly over and over again within the same query doesn't make it any easier to understand. Perhaps you could use some letters that are easily confused with digits.